# Is it possible to find a list of all variables in internet explorer using vba

Tags: vba, variables, internet-explorer, find, frames

here is my situation. For work we use a Java based system that pulls account information when a call comes through. I have created an access form that uses vba for auto identifying account types and properties based on the account number, however the number needs to be typed in manually the first time and then saved to the database.

For privacy reasons, I would rather not save data even though I don't keep more than 5 digits of an account number.

If I can find a way to call the needed variables from the open page then it would be unnecessary to save the values.

I have already got code to recognize the already opened page and set oWin to IE. However the site uses frames within frames and finding a single variable has been driving me crazy.

So here's the question: is there a vba way to list every variable and its path using vba while searching through all frames?

I only have access to the source code by clicking view source and developer (f12) is disabled on all computers I have access to.

I know the variable exists and in the source is written as

MerchantNumber =xxxxxx2290001234

X's added for security by me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I cannot understand you question as it is written right now: it feels like it is a little bit too broad. Have a look at it, then maybe try to shrink the information to the minimum necessary: most likely, you can refine your question by analyzing the problem deeper and highlighting the actual piece of code that needs intervention.

Comment: Use the frames collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are talking here is DIV on the web page and not variables.

Source code shows the HTML code and variables not get displayed in it.

Generally information is displayed in DIVs  or Tags and You can try to access this information using VBA code by finding those DIVs using its ID or Name or by any other property.

Here is one VBA code example to access values from iframe.

```
Sub demo3()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True


    URL = "http://localhost/346.html"

    IE.navigate URL

    Do While IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set doc = IE.document

    Dim iframeDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set iframeDoc = doc.frames("frame1").document
    If iframeDoc Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "IFrame with name 'iframename' was not found."
        IE.Quit
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim element As MSHTML.HTMLDivElement
    Set element = iframeDoc.querySelector("#div1")
    If element Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "element within iframe was not found."
        IE.Quit
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Debug.Print element.innerHTML
    End If

  '  Set IE = Nothing
  '  Set objElement = Nothing
  '  Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

You can refer this example and try to develop your own code may help to get desired results. If you have any further questions then let us know about it.